# Remove Numbers and Turn into a List

Tags: python, list, replace, split

#

PYTHON
A clearer way of asking the question is:

If I have a string as follows:
'PALM BEACH.Race 6GaveaRace 5MaronasRace 7IOWARace 3ORANGE PARK.Race 5'

How do I turn that string into:
Palm Beach, Gavea, Maronas, Iowa, Orange Park

So that is, make each item in the list 'title'(ie. Uppercase first letter and the rest lower case), delete the numbers and the word 'Race'.

I am setting up to export to Excel.

Thanks in advance - Angus

#

Comment: The site isn't available in the US, so it's hard to replicate what you are doing. But what do you get when you try `print(type(Z))`? Also, can you edit your question and show `Y`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and some string manipulation:

```
import re
>>> s = 'PALM BEACH.Race 6GaveaRace 5MaronasRace 7IOWARace 3ORANGE PARK.Race 5'
>>> # Split by the race and folowed by a digit
>>> race_names = re.split('Race \d+', s)
>>> def format_name(name):
...     # Remove the trailing period on some race names
...     name = name.rstrip('.')
...     # Change name to title case
...     name = name.title()
...     return name
>>> # Format the name and remove any empty entries in the list
>>> race_names = [format_name(name) for name in race_names if name]
>>> list(race_names)
['Palm Beach', 'Gavea', 'Maronas', 'Iowa', 'Orange Park']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without importing any library:

```
races = """PALM BEACH.Race 6GaveaRace 5MaronasRace 7IOWARace 3ORANGE PARK.Race 5"""
''.join([ch if not ch.isdigit() else 'xxx' for ch in races.replace('Race ','')]).split('xxx')
```

Output:

```
['PALM BEACH.', 'Gavea', 'Maronas', 'IOWA', 'ORANGE PARK.', '']
```